# refresh page in js when it comes in css responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible that when the page is on css responsive it will refresh the page using javascript or jquery?

example if I have this css code :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 826px){
    #divid{
    top:80px;
}
}
```

I want to refresh the page if the width will equal to 826px.
for now I have these js code:

```
var descTop = $('#divid').eq(0).css('top');
    if (descTop == "80px"){
           window.location.reload();
    }
```

but it won't work, but when I try to manually refresh it, it will infinitely wont stop of reloading.

does my idea possible? if yes then  how will I deal with it?

Comment: Why do you want to specifically reload a page?

Comment: so that my other javascript will be loaded and call when it responsive

Comment: Wouldn't it defeat the purpose of responsive design if you reload the page for various sizes?

Comment: In responsive web site, the reloading the page is wrong method.. so proceed with media query alone    
http://stackcomplete.com/media-queries-for-adaptive-to-responsive-websites/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are refreshing the page based on the size being less that 826 pixels which is always the case once you are below that amount. So the refresh will loop.

You need to look at attaching to the onWinodowResize event:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var descTop = $('#divid').width()
if (descTop < 826){
       window.location.reload();
}
});
```

Then  you need to reload once. But only when the user resizes.

Also you code is comparing two strings not a integer value for the width;

Comment: Seeing your comment above if you want to trigger JS by reloading the page, why not wrap the code in a function and call that function when the resize event results in the object size being less than 826